# Swift Realm: Can't update subset of object with primary key

Tags: swift, realm

[image]

Users is of type Object, as required by Realm. If I use

```
let userObject = Users()
self.realm.add(userObject, update: true)
```

then there are no errors, but it overwrites my object. What am I doing wrong for updating a subset of an object?

UPDATE:-

Attempted the suggested solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify a primary key for your object so that each object can be uniquely identified. Check the following section of the documentation to see how to set the primary key:

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys

I used the sample project you provided and modified the code as follows (note that this is for Xcode 7 beta 6 and Swift 2.0) and it works fine without any errors or issues:

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    try realm.write {
    realm.create(Users.self, value:["userEmail":"test@test.com", "name":"Test User"], update:true)
    realm.create(Users.self, value:["userEmail":"another@test.com", "name":"Another"], update:true)
    }
} catch {
    NSLog("Realm error")
}
```

Comment: primary key is already added with override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "userEmail"
    }

Comment: If you can send me the project, I can root around a bit to see what is going on. It's harder to troubleshoot (at least for me) without seeing the full project in action ...

Comment: I've recreated the issue with a new project to simplify the scenario. Feel free to download the project here: [TestProject](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9oELEUeRSS7OElkaHBZSkloQzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is with Xcode 7 beta 6 and I modified the `Users` object to add another property (to see if it gets overwritten or updated) and it seems to work as expected. Here's my code:
`realm.create(Users.self, value:["userEmail":"test@test.com", "name":"Test User"], update:true)
realm.create(Users.self, value:["userEmail":"another@test.com", "name":"Another"], update:true)`

Answer (score 0):

Since using `add` requires passing along a standalone object, there's no way to tell which properties you intend to overwrite -- using `create` with a dictionary is indeed the proper way to do this. To silence the erroneous compiler error, you might want to add an `_ =` to the block, which will fix the type inference.

---

For example,

```
realm.write {
  _ = realm.create(...)
}
```

Comment: Am relatively new to iOS development, so would you be able to provide an example as to where the _ could be added?

Comment: thank you, but the compiler error remains. Have updated the original post with the new screenshot.

Comment: What about adding a plain `return` statement at the end of the `write` block?

Comment: if I try the 'return' statement, I get the error "cannot invoke 'create' with an argument list of...." with or without the '_ =' in front

Comment: I am using Realm 0.95 if that helps. Primary key is set to "userEmail" with override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "userEmail"
    }

Comment: I've recreated the issue with a new project to simplify the scenario. Feel free to download the project here: [TestProject](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9oELEUeRSS7OElkaHBZSkloQzQ/view?usp=sharing)